# Editor.js: how to add unique block id for each editor element as 'id' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, editorjs

I use Editor.js in my ReactJS application. Everything perfect except I can't pass unique block id as 'id' attribute.

For example, data is:

```
{
    "time": 1658299444298,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "id": "sheNwCUP5A",
            "data": {
                "text": "Acceptable Use Policy",
                "level": 2
            },
            "type": "header"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.25.0"
}
```

and DOM-tree is

```
<div class="codex-editor__redactor" style="padding-bottom: 300px;">
  <div class="ce-block">
   <div class="ce-block__content">
    <h2 class="ce-header" contenteditable="false" data-placeholder="">Audit Policy</h2> 
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To implement anchor links inside current document I need 'id' attribute for each element passed from data.

```
...
<h2 id="sheNwCUP5A" class="ce-header" contenteditable="false" data-placeholder="">Audit Policy</h2>
...
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue right now and I see that it's necessary to put in the EditorJS instantiation the minHeight: 1.

```
 new EditorJS({
    ...
    minHeight: 1,
    tools: {
       ...
    },
    ...
  });
```

That's crazy, but that's the way I found to fix it for now.